# Jboss SOAP implement

Tags: jboss, soa

```
public class CamelProccer2 implements Processor {

public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    OutputSOATest2 out = new OutputSOATest2();
    List soaList = exchange.getFromEndpoint().getEndpointKey()(List.class);
    InputSOATest2 inputSOATest2 = (InputSOATest2) soaList.get(0);
    out.setResult("GoodBye " + inputSOATest2.getTest().toString());
    exchange.getOut().setBody(out);

}
```

> i want to get endpoint name as a output of this

implemented SOAP Service which get input and give a output after processing the input above i attached my processor code,here i want to get endpoint method name as the output

Comment: implemented SOAP Service which get input and give a output after processing the input above i attached my  processor code,here i want to get endpoint key or end point URI as the output.

Comment: List soaList = exchange.getFromEndpoint().getEndpointKey()(List.class);  this code given me an error

Comment: Hey @SameeraAthukorala, please update the question with that info. I am sure it help people to understand your question better, and by that increasing the chance for a proper answer. Just click `edit`.